# VB.net get specific characters from listbox

Tags: vb.net

I want to get specific characters from listbox, but I don't know how to do it properly. I already used search (tried because I don't know how properly to name) but get nothing.

**So i have this line in my listbox:**

```
 1,2014-01-01,Text,Text,XYZ123,Text,Text
```

How do i need to get only **XYZ123**? Its always same format, 3 letters and 3 numbers.

Thank you.

Comment: use a regex. clean and easy http://regexr.com/394hj

Comment: Is you problem accessing the text from the listbox or extracting the substring from the string or both?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a [Regular Expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc(v=vs.110).aspx)

The Regex of XYZ123 = `\w{3}\d{3}`

**First solution:**
Based on a small console application:

```
    Dim i As String = "1,2014-01-01,Text,Text,**XYZ123**,Text,Text"
    For Each Str As String In i.Split(",")
        Dim match As Match = Regex.Match(Str, "\w{3}\d{3}")
        If match.Success Then
            Console.WriteLine(Str)
        End If
    Next

    Console.ReadLine()
```

**Second (better) solution:**

Based on the comment of [Chinz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3085187/chinz) (all credits belong to him)

```
    Dim i As String = "1,2014-01-01,Text,Text,**XYZ123**,Text,Text"
    Console.WriteLine(Regex.Match(i, "\w{3}\d{3}").Value)
    Console.ReadLine()
```

Comment: Why not simply `\w{3}\d{3}` instead of `([A-z][A-z][A-z][\d][\d][\d])`?

Comment: Could be, i'm not that good with Regex. will test it directly. Thnx though

Comment: do you really need to split the value if you're using regex? Extra work through.

Comment: If you just want the **XYZ123** then yes. He clearly requests only the  **XYZ123** part

Comment: perhaps this? **Dim output As String = Regex.Match(yourString, "\w{3}\d{3}").Value**

Comment: Thank you. I used split method (as user3801728 suggested). And this "\w{3}\d{3}" was everything I needed. Thank you guys for your help. This website is OP!

Answer (score 0):

if all the strings have the same overall format you could split on "**" and get the [1] from the plitted

Comment: There are no `*` characters in the string. It was just a formatting accident.

Comment: can you split on "," then?

Comment: Yes, thank you i splitted ";". I'm new in vb.net, so I didin't know about split method.